# How to bulk refactor class / cs file names in a large TFS managed Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, refactoring, resharper, naming-conventions

I'm currently working within a monolithic solution that is a conglomeration of several smaller projects and the result of many developers efforts. However, one of these efforts was not the creation of a standards document regarding naming practices for test classes. As such I have over 1500 individual  test classes that may have a suffix of "Test", "Tester", or "Tests".

Is there a good way to batch rename all the *[Test|Tester].cs files within our solution to *Tests.cs taking into account the preexisting TFS and project file structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that seemed to work for me was to do a Find & Replace via a regular expression across targeted test projects within my solution.

In the standared Visual Studio Find and Replace Dialog

I searched for `public\W+class\W+([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)Test(er)?\b`

and replaced with the captured group of `public class $1Tests`

within all files matching *Test.cs;*Tester.cs

Importantly, and for reasons unknown to me, if I didn't check the "Keep modified files open after Replace All" the find and replace would fail

eg:

[image: magic search dialog]

Once the find and replace operation was completed I used Resharper's [Move Types Into Matching Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Refactorings__Move_Types_into_Matching_Files.html) refactor function on the test packages in order to update references in both TFS and various project files.

Answer (score 0):

Use a local workspace and your bulk renaming tool of choice. It doesn't have to be within Visual Studio. A local workspace will allow changes to the structure of the project to be made from any tool and still "noticed" by the pending changes window or `tf.exe`.

You'll still have to update the `*.*proj` files to take into account that the files have been renamed, of course.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on a Bulk Renaming tool that will account for modifying the actual file names *and* the actual class names to reflect the name change? I couldn't think of any so didn't answer this question.